# Error while updating product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nebula

When I updating my product that uses Nebula widget I get the following error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid,1.0.0.201508142003. Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile33130143692620178.jar An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile33130143692620178.jar Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.source,1.0.0.201508142003. Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7737537058941296546.jar An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7737537058941296546.jar Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.feature,1.0.0.201508142003. Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3244476115691037436.jar An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3244476115691037436.jar

Installing Nebula Grid into empty Eclipse works fine. Any ideas what can be causing this error?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you talking about?

Comment: This is in Eclipse Indigo

Comment: I don't really understand the nature of the problem. Both versions in my Nebula feature and on Nebula update site are the same.